# Why is Guild.get_channel returning a none object sometimes in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So i got this code, but the get_channel often returns a none object but sometime it replies the discord channel object. Why is this like that? Is there a better way?
The script is for showing stats of the server in the channels.

```py
#Checking the channels & Server Stats
@bot.event
async def on_connect():

    while True:
        #Checking the channels
        filename = "/home/pi/discordbot/CCreated.json"
        with open('/home/pi/discordbot/CCreated.json', 'r') as f:
            channels_created = json.load(f)
                
        for content in channels_created['timers']:
            # find raiding
            Guild = bot.get_guild(771495836701425725)
            channel_id = int(content)

            # finds the members ([] when noone is in)
            voice_channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
            voice_ch_str = str(voice_channel.members)
            #Testing if someone is in there
            if voice_ch_str == "[]":
                channel_get = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
                await channel_get.delete()

                with open("/home/pi/discordbot/CCreated.json", "r") as f:
                    data = json.load(f)

                    data["timers"].pop(f"{data['timers'][content]['channel_id']}")

                with open("/home/pi/discordbot/CCreated.json", "w") as f:
                    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)

#Server Stats

#Getting User Count
Guild = bot.get_guild(771495836701425725)
member_count = len(Guild.members)  # includes bots
true_member_count = len([m for m in Guild.members if not m.bot])  # doesn't include bots

#Getting Streamer Count
role = Guild.get_role(841596562689097729)
#print(type(role))
#print(len(role.members))
streamer_count = len(role.members)

#Setting the new Stats
streamer_stats = Guild.get_channel(968570363103568012)
await streamer_stats.edit(name=f"\U0001F4CA STREAMER: {streamer_count}")
```

Comment: In some discord.py version IDs are supposed to be strings. This seems unlikely to be the issue though.

Comment: Can you show the context of the code snippet in the question? Is it in a command, event listener, etc?

Comment: @EricJin I will as soon im at home. Its within an while loop with something else, because it of course has to be in a while loop and its in on_ready i believe because it has to start in any way, of course i could split those 2 and put them in role update and yk. But i first tried this method. But when im at home, i will add the rest

Comment: If it’s in on ready then your bot cache is completely empty. So you will need to use fetch rather than get in this case.

Comment: @EricJin so i know added the whole def. I will try it with fetch

Comment: `on_connect` does not let you access the api. You need it in on ready, and just make a flag so you don’t call it too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.
I put the role check in the member update and "filtered" for the specific role and everytime someone gets it or loses it, it checks how many users the role have and sets then the channel name.

The User Count is now in on_member_remove /join and everytime this happens the bot checks how many user are on the Server and sets the channel name.

Answer (score 1):

There is a key difference between the `get` and the `fetch` methods defined in the `Client` class. That difference is: `get` returns a **cached** result by the bot, while `fetch` returns an API call, aka a request made that provides global information on the requested item.

This comes with a few downsides.

using `fetch` usually returns objects/instances with much less attributes to use since global information is not as much as cached information, which essentially is items that the bot itself can see. In short:

```py
Client.get_channel(some_id) # returns a cached channel, has all the documented attributes

# not the same as below
await Client.fetch_channel(some_id) # returns a channel fetched directly from the API, does lack a few of the documented attributes
```

Comment: Interesting, i tried it like that, but the main problem looks like that the role returns a none object. But there is no fetch role :/